# I want to know the meaning of a line in java

Tags: java, casting, comparison, type-conversion

What is the meaing of below line of Java code

```
  class Dog {
    int size;

    Dog(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.size == ((Dog) o).size; // im not getting whats the meaning of this line
    }
}
```

I want to know the meaning of following line:

```
return this.size== ((Dog)o).size;
```

Comment: return this.size== ((Dog)o).size; // im not getting whats the mening of this line } }

Comment: it is casting the object o to Dog and getting the size

Comment: thanks its downcasting ryt??

Comment: Where is the `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 3):

This is the meaning: the current object's `size` variable is compared for equality with the other object's `size` variable. The result, a `boolean` value, is returned as the result of the `equals` method.

An implicit assertion is made that the other object is of the same type. A proper implementation of `equals` must *not* throw a `ClassCastException` in that case, but rather return `false`. Therefore this implementation does not comply with the contract of the `Object#equals` method.

To me this looks like the developer was feeling smart and "found out" a way to concisely implement `equals`. A correct, but still quite concise, implementation would go like this:

```
return o instanceof Dog && ((Dog)o).size == this.size;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an odd implementation of the `equals` method.

It will take object `o` and attempt to cast it to an object of type `Dog`. It will then compare the size of that dog to the size of `this` dog.

This is a problematic method since if we were to pass in something that cannot be cast to a dog(a socket, for example) it would throw a ClassCastException, which is a big no-no with `equals(`. It **must** return false if the objects can't be cast for comparison.

I would rewrite it as follows:

```
boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o==null) return false;
    if(this==o) return true;
    if(!o instanceOf Dog) return false;
    return this.size==((Dog) o).size;
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't check for null.

Comment: @Robadob Sorry, fixed.

Comment: I think your code already checks for null (prior to edit). `o instanceOf Dog` => if `o` is null => `null instanceof Dog` => false...`!null` is the problem and can be fixed using `!(o instanceOf Dog)`

Comment: @boxed__l True, though making it clear there's a nullcheck is actually better.

Comment: BTW the first check is a micro-optimization which is in danger of being a micro-pessimization: it bets on a large proportion of checks of the object against itself, otherwise it is just an extra check. The heavier the overall complexity of `equals`, the more it pays off.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Still good to get the OP into the habit lest the time comes when he compares large data objects by complex walks thoughout both objects.\

Answer (score 1):

```
((Dog)o).size

(Dog)o // means Cast o into Dog.


this.size = castedDog.size //means assign the `size` of current object the same value as casteddog object's size
```

Answer (score 1):

1) this will cast the Object o to Dog class
    if passing other than Dog object then it will throw Casing Exceptioin
2) then it compares the attribute of o to the current attribute - size
     then it will return boolean value

Answer (score 0):

casting the object o to `Dog` and getting the size of the `object`. And `((Dog)o).size` will return `int` size.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two dogs: dog1 and dog2, and let's say you call dog1.equals( dog2 ).

this.size, in English would translate to: "the size of this dog"

==, in English would translate to: "has the same value as"

( (Dog) o ).size, in English would translate to: "the size of o, and o is a dog"

Put together:
The size of this dog has the same value as the size of o, and o is a dog.

Since you are calling dog1.equals( dog2 ), then "this dog" refers to dog1, and "o" refers to dog2, giving you:

The size of dog1 has the same value as the size of dog2, and dog2 is a dog.